# MathJax in tag excerpts

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, tag-wikis

When writing a tag excerpt incorporating MathJax is fine for the tag page itself, however in the preview given when hovering/tagging a question the MathJax is not compiled making the TeX code as distraction rather than a contribution.

I do believe that the TeX code in the preview is essential, but more input from the community, and/or a developer's reply would be... wunderbar.

Comment: I think it is the same for other Markdown stuff - the hovering preview does not interprets it right.

Comment: In view of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6574/latex-in-tag-wikis the information given in the answer to this is now obsolete. Maybe this could be marked duplicate, or we should indicate in some other way that situation has been changed since this was posted.

Answer (score 2):

How essential is the MathJax in the tag wiki *excerpt?*

Obviously MathJax will render fine in the full tag wiki, which the excerpt does link to in the drop-down.

Comment: If we intend to guide users into choosing the right tag, and our most immediate tool is the excerpt then it is essential for a mathematical website.

Comment: @Asaf: I disagree with the necessity of using TeX in the excerpts. Ideally I think we should encourage writing the excerpts Wikipedia style (by that I mean the introductory blurb) and without mathematical notation.

Comment: @willie why don't you try your hand at a few and see what you think.. I generally find "try it and see how it feels" works best. I am open to either solution here.

Comment: @jeff: I'm pretty sure I've written at least a dozen tag wikis, and have never found it necessary to use mathjax in the excerpts.

Comment: ok then @asaf sounds like my comment should have been directed at you -- "try it!" :)

Comment: I will definitely give it a try, but I do not agree that MathJax is unneeded, as I believe that the small size of the excerpt makes it simple to JIT-compile when needed without much delay. I will try to edit some excerpt that I wrote before it was 100% clear what the excerpts are for in this system of tags. (It may take a couple of days though.)